# Unable to expand this solution in the form of Hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I want to write this solution into hyper geometric function

```
(-I + Sqrt[3] - 2 I u)^(1/6 (3 - Sqrt[15])) (I + Sqrt[3] + 2 I u)^(
1/6 (3 + Sqrt[15])) C[1] + (
I (-I + Sqrt[3] - 2 I u)^(1/2 + Sqrt[5/3]/2) (I + Sqrt[3] + 2 I u)^(
1/2 - Sqrt[5/3]/2) C[2])/(4 Sqrt[5])
```

Comment: As there are a bazillion different hypergeometric functions, there's probably more than one that can give your solution. Do you have some particular hypergeometric family in mind?

Comment: I have to convert this solution into this form; ```_C1*(2*u+1+I*sqrt(3))^(-1/2+1/2*I)*(-2*u-1+I*sqrt(3))*hypergeom([3/2-1/2*I, 1/2-1/2*I], [1-I], (2*I)*sqrt(3)/(2*u+1+I*sqrt(3)))+_C2*(2*u+1+I*sqrt(3))^(-1/2-1/2*I)*(-2*u-1+I*sqrt(3))*hypergeom([1/2+1/2*I, 3/2+1/2*I], [1+I], (2*I)*sqrt(3)/(2*u+1+I*sqrt(3)))```

Comment: Assuming that hypergeom() in your code is the 2F1 one, I tried to match the coefficients C[1], C[2] (as they appear linearly) by evaluating the functions at 2 points and solving for them, but it seems they don't match. Either there's a bug in the code or in fact the solutions don't match in general. If this question is based on a paper etc, please post a link (arXiv etc).

Comment: Actually, I want to match maple and Mathematica solution. The maple code is as follows:`p(u) :=1/((u^(2)+u+1)); ode := diff(x(u), u, u) +1/(2)*p(u)*x(u) = 0; sol=dsolve(ode,);  display( [ plot( p(u),u=-8..8,  color=black), plot( sol,                       [u,x(u)], u=-8..8, color=blue )]                                       );  ` .'x(u) = _C1*(2*u+1+I*sqrt(3))^(-1/2+1/2*I)*(-2*u-1+I*sqrt(3))*hypergeom([3/2-1/2*I, 1/2-1/2*I], [1-I], (2*I)*sqrt(3)/(2*u+1+I*sqrt(3)))+_C2*(2*u+1+I*sqrt(3))^(-1/2-1/2*I)*(-2*u-1+I*sqrt(3))*hypergeom([1/2+1/2*I, 3/2+1/2*I], [1+I], (2*I)*sqrt(3)/(2*u+1+I*sqrt(3)))'

Comment: The  mathematica code is the following:   ```DSolve[D[x[u], {u, 2}] + (1/2)*1/(u^2 + u + 1)^2 x[u] == 0, 
  x[u], {u}];``` ```(-I + Sqrt[3] - 2 I u)^(1/6 (3 - Sqrt[15])) (I + Sqrt[3] + 2 I u)^(
  1/6 (3 + Sqrt[15])) C[1] + (
 I (-I + Sqrt[3] - 2 I u)^(1/2 + Sqrt[5/3]/2) (I + Sqrt[3] + 2 I u)^(
  1/2 - Sqrt[5/3]/2) C[2])/(4 Sqrt[5])``` .Both the solutions in maple and mathematica are not matching

Comment: You seem to have `p[u]^2` in the _Mathematica_ equation.